# Как получить json от API

Tags: php, json

API перадает на мой php-файл json.

Как мне его получить и разобрать?

Передается в формате `$_POST`

Вопрос: Как получить строку json и поместить в переменную.

```
$perem = $_POST[?]
```

Что должно быть на месте вопроса? Или как-то можно узнать по другому, что посылает сервер АПИ?

Comment: "*Что должно быть на месте вопроса?*" - это должно быть написано в документации по API.

Comment: var_dump($_POST); смотрите, что пришло. потом $json = json_decode($POST['whatyouneed' ]);

Comment: Вы разберитесь сначала, где сервер. Сервер - это принимающая сторона. Если данные приходят прямо в телезапроса, то `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));`

Comment: С помощью file_get_contents('php://input') получаю строку такого типа:
leads[status][0][id]=37369578&leads[status][0][name]=Проверка&leads[status][0][status_id]=8182600&leads[status][0][price]=0&leads[status][0][responsible_user_id]=343542&leads[status][0][last_modified]=1433546071
Как из этого сделать нормальный массив?

Comment: отредактируйте ответ и поместите это  туда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы написали в комментариях, это не json. Это формат query. C ней следует поступить следующим образом

```
$str = 'leads[status][0][id]=37369578&leads[status][0][name]=Проверка&leads[status][0][s‌​tatus_id]=8182600&leads[status][0][price]=0&leads[status][0][responsible_user_id]‌​=343542&leads[status][0][last_modified]=1433546071';
parse_str ($str);
var_dump($leads);
```

результат

```
array(1) {
  ["status"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(6) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(8) "37369578"
      ["name"]=>
      string(16) "Проверка"
      ["s‌​tatus_id"]=>
      string(7) "8182600"
      ["price"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["responsible_user_id"]=>
      string(6) "343542"
      ["last_modified"]=>
      string(10) "1433546071"
    }
  }
}
```